# Sorting of Date Format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I am using a query in oracle which gives the below result (its a kind of month-wise transaction report):

```
Month   Total    Submitted    Approved
--------------------------------------
DEC-14   2      2           0
APR-15   17     12          5
SEP-14   1      1           0
FEB-15   7      4           3
JUL-15   1      1           0
JAN-15   18     4           14
MAR-15   2      1           1
OCT-14   2     (null)   (null)
JUN-15   136    91          45
JUN-14   1      1           0
MAY-15   179    63          116
```

I want to get the result in a sorted format, like JUN-14,SEP-14,OCT-14,DEC-14,JAN-15....so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the Month column based on? if it's based on a date data type column, you can use it for order by.

Comment: what is the data type of month?

Comment: @GajenDas Please post the query used to derive this output.

Comment: @GajenDas how you are displaying month column, did the source column is one(1) or you are joining the two dates for display(2)?
eg:(1) TO_char(hiredate,'mon-yy')

Comment: @GajenDas Did any of the answers prove helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`order by date_column desc` where *date_column* is the column that holds the date. This will order by the *date_column* in descending order.

Use `asc` to order in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

If month data type in character format you have to use

```
    select * from table_name 
order by to_char(to_date(month,'mm/yy'),'yy') asc,to_char(to_date(month,'mm/yy'),'mm') asc
```

if it is in date

```
  select * from table_name 
order by to_char(month,'yy') asc,to_char(month,'mm') asc
```

Answer (score 0):

i assumed that you were using  the following for displaying month column data.

> TO_char(hiredate,'mon-yy')

if you used this then it will be easy for sorting them.

```
select your column list from table order by source_date_column asc;
```

for reference use the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fb8e/1/1)